# Overriding Django Password Reset Email Directory

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to change the location of templates for Django password reset emails, which are by default stored in `/registration`. Any ideas on how to do this? I currently have:

```
class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def save(self):
        super(CustomPasswordResetForm, self).save(email_template_name='<custom_directory>/<file>.html')
```

which is throwing a

```
TypeError at /passreset/
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request' at 
venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py in password_reset, line 160
```

Comment: Do you want to change location of the templates because you want to override them?

Comment: I am just wondering why are you not catching / passing *args, **kw to overridden method?